# Adding WP Post Types: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm currently studying WordPress and want to create a custom Post Type and have copied code from a tutorial that I am following. The code in the tutorial works but when I copy/paste it into custom page template, I get the following error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in
>   /home/databasename/public_html/wptheme/demo/wp-content/themes/name/albums.php
>   on line 3"

I have Googled the issue for hours and there are multiple options but the issue is that I am a beginner and don't know exactly what to change. I know that the problem is on line 3 but that's it. Shown below is my code that is located in my custom page template. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <?php 

    add_action('init', function() { /*this is line 3*/
    register_post_type( 'album', array(
        'public' => true,
        'label' => 'Album',
        'labels' => array('add_new_item' => 'Add New Album')
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
    )); 
});
```

Comment: It seems wherever this code is running, they are not using PHP 5.3. Lambda functions are only available since then.

Comment: You are probably using a version of PHP ( < 5.3) that doesn't yet support anonymous functions using `function() {}` - you'll have to use `create_function()` instead or update

Comment: Could it be that the video tutorial is outdated? If so, what should I change in the code to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running an outdated version of php, i.e. php <5.3, which does not support [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which are used in this code.

While you could rewrite the code to use a named function, or [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php), you should really just update your php installation to a version from this decade. php 5.2 (or even older versions) is [not supported anymore](http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-08-23-1), and therefore insecure.

Additionally, your code is missing a comma at the end of one of the lines:

```
    'labels' => array('add_new_item' => 'Add New Album')
//                                                      ^^
```

Comment: I am testing the site on a live server (Hostgator) and if I'm not misstaken, they use PHP 5.3 but I could be wrong.

Comment: For whatever reason, the folks at hostgator run a totally outdated version of php. [Here's there help article on how to switch to 5.3](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-questions/php-5-3). I'd also consider switching hosting to a service that runs supported php versions by default, and allows you to use modern ones like php 5.4.

Comment: Thank you Phihag for your help. Could you tell me how it's possible I can use any WordPress Theme on that server but not my own theme?

Comment: Sorry Phihag, it has partially worked. I have updated the PHP to 5.3 but I now have a new error after updating: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /home/db/public_html/theme/demo/wp-content/themes/name/albums.php on line 8 of the same code shown in my first post. Should I create a new thread or do you have a sollution?

Comment: Updated the answer (the code was in the question). In general, feel free to ask questions, as long as every question stands on its own, and includes intention, code, and error message, just like this one.

Comment: Phihag, thanks for the support! After adding a comma after 'labels' => array('add_new_item' => 'Add New Album'), I'm getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home/db/public_html/theme/demo/wp-content/themes/name/albums.php on line 9. The updated code is at the top of the thread.

Comment: Please do **not** edit the question to include additional code with different problems. That leads to question that's confusing to other users with the same problem. Instead, simply **ask a new question**, and *maybe* add a comment `I've run into another problem and have asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/my/new/question` here. I rolled back the change in the question in order to avoid confusion for other users with the same problem. It looks like you inadvertently added another `)` in the `'supports'` line.

Comment: You, my kind sir, are awesome! That worked! As I'm still a beginner to WordPress and PHP, could you perhaps point me to a tutorial that covers the comma's and brackets. I don't know when to use them. Anyhow, thank you so much! How do I thank you here? I'm new to Stackoverflow as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about tutorials. The [php manual's reference](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php) (particulary about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)) may not be the most exciting read, but it's exact. To quote myself: If this (or any other) answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). As soon as you reach a [reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/141962) of 15, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) good answers.